# Checking Text exist or not?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Say I am on StackOverFlow "All Questions" page.

1. I want to search for a user say "user2402616" (which is present on 3rd page) on first page.
2. If not present then click on next button until it is found.

I tried below code using Xpath but getting  error.

```
    boolean bPres = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'user2402616')]")).isDisplayed();
    System.out.println(bPres);

    while (!bPres) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'next')]")).click();
    }
```

Comment: Which error? Could you edit your question to include the error message?

Comment: On the first page it is searching for object "//a[contains(text(),'user2402616')]" i.e, a link "user2402616" which is not present on first page. So giving NoSuchElement Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Since the xpath has text in both the cases i.e for clicking on the user and the next button . You can use the By.linkText method and pass in the value which you want to click

```
 boolean bPres = driver.findElement(By.linkText("user2402616")).isDisplayed();
 System.out.println(bPres);

 while (!bPres) {
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("next").click();
 }
```